# Изменение яркости RGB цвета

Tags: цвета

Допустим есть произвольный цвет RGB, и этот цвет - это 100% яркости, соответственно 0% - это 0,0,0 (черный). Подскажите формулу расчета цвета от эталонного с указанием яркости в процентах.

Есть мысль, что все проще чем я думаю:

```
double adjust = 0.5; // 0.1 - 10%, 1 - 100%

int r = (int) (r1 * adjust);
int g = (int) (g1 * adjust);
int b = (int) (b1 * adjust);
```

Так ли это?

Comment: Яркость ведь в HSV описывается? Значит нужно RGB перевести в HSV, поменять яркость и сделать обратную конвертацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам скорее всего стоит использовать другую цветовую модель. Сконвертируйте ваш цвет с RGB -> HSB, далее уже меняйте яркость/насышенность, не меняя цетовой тон.

**Обозначения HSB:**

- H - цветовой тон (hue)
- S - насыщенность (saturation)
- B - яркость (brightness)